# How do i uninstall ODK Central?

Tags: odk, central

I have tried installing ODK Central on Digital Ocean. I need to uninstall it because the installation was not succesfull.

I tried reinstalling and expected to log into the server and create an admin account but it does not work. Then, i decided to start the installation from scratch.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? In general, https://forum.getodk.org/ is going to be a better place for ODK help and I recommend posting there.